# JMeter: Is it possible to assign a UI value to a JMeter variable

Tags: jmeter

I want to login in to an email server and read the value '5' from inbox(5) in a variable to use it further.Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is about to log into Mail Server web interface - it is "classic" [JMeter correlation](http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/correlation.html) example which can be handled by [Regular Expression Extractor](http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/correlation.html). Regular expression you need to use will look like

```
(?i)inbox\((\d+)\)
```

So you will be able to extract the value into a JMeter Variable and use it in the test.

By the way, you can use [Mail Reader Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler) which talks directly to the email server via POP3 or IMAP protocol and you will be able to test email server directly and abstract from web interface. See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) guide for more information on email servers testing using JMeter.

Comment: I tried to use both the cases. For regular expression extractor I gave the following values :                                                                                          Reference Name :Inbox
Regular expression :(?i)inbox\((\d+)\)
Template :[0-9]{3,6}
Match No. (0 for random) :0
Default value :0
This is not working.Am I missing somthing? I understand that using Main Reader Sampler I can read the messages but are you sure this is possible to extract the value in a variable?